# adb shows devices as offline but system_profiler detects the devices fine

Tags: usb, adb, offline

I have several devices (mix of tablets and phones) connected to my mac mini. Some of them are connected directly while some are connected by a good quality hub.

```
$  system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep -i serial
   Serial Number: 015d2109ed4c0c18
     Serial Number: 4dfcbd091f3a5023
     Serial Number: 000ee30e7de4cf
     Serial Number: 4100018996d37000
     Serial Number: 0123456789ABCDEF
   Serial Number: FA35FW901634
   Serial Number: 2021bbaa
```

For sometime, adb detects all these devices fine.

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
4100018996d37000        device
0123456789ABCDEF        device
000ee30e7de4cf  device
4dfcbd091f3a5023        device
2021bbaa        device
FA35FW901634    device
015d2109ed4c0c18        device
```

But with time, these devices goes in offline state irrespective of the way they are connected (direct or via hub). Even when these are in offline state, as reported by adb, system_profiler still detects them fine. This means that Mac mini is still seeing these devices but adb is not.

I am using original cables that came with the phone. Why do they go in offline state? Only thing that get the devices back is physically re-connecting the devices. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: That might be due to power-saving settings (may sound wierd as USB is a power supply, but the algorithm used might not take that into consideration). I know there's a setting in the developers section to keep the display on when power connected, so you could use that. Alternatively, you could set your WiFi policy to keep WiFi "always active" on power-connected. Or build something yourself with *Tasker* and the *Secure Settings* Plugin.

Comment: @Izzy I'll take a look at it for sure. Wifi is always on. I must add though that all the devices are fully charged (via usb).

Comment: I was aware of the latter, that's why I wrote *the algorithm used might not take that into consideration* (could be a generic powersave util). But I'd thought WiFi active should keep it in a "wake state". That leaves the display and Tasker tricks. Easiest approach might be a Tasker profile with the condition "Power (USB)", and a Task that loops over "`ping -c 1 <whatever>`" followed by a "Wait <30s>". Just thinking aloud :)

Answer (score 1):

We've been looking for an answer to this for some several months. Unfortunately, the most hopeful response I've seen is this one, which suggests moving the Mac Mini to Linux, whose USB stack is described as 'more forgiving':

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727314/resetting-android-device-when-it-goes-to-offline-mode-during-automation

We're going to try shifting to a spare (PC-based) Linux box for the time being; I'll try to remember to report back whether it's more reliable.

Comment: We stayed using PCs but forgot that we periodically killed adb because of the Mac usb stack - so our test run script still kills adb before running, even though we presumably don't need to! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the "Stay awake" setting under Developer options to keep it "active" while connected to the USB.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, usually what i do is , stop the adb server, use the adb kill-server command. You can then restart the server by sending any adb command. Please check if that works

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. The adb devices command was giving device offline response.

Then I stopped adb server by executing the following command.
adb server-kill

Then again started daemon by adb devices command.
Connection request was promted on my android phone and I gave it .
Then I could see my device online

This worked for me hope it would also resolve yours